# Split function on arrays in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am attempting to use the `split` function on a string, the seperator I am using is `"/"`. There are multiple occurrences of `/` and I would like to split using the last `/`.

```
let url = https://learn.edu/d2l/login?sessionExpired=1&target=%2fd2l%2fhome     
let beforeLastSlash, afterLastSlash = url.split("/")
```

Currently the `beforeLastSlash = "https://learn.edu"` and `afterLastSlash  = "d2l"`. I was reading mdn and saw that `.split()` method has a `limit` parameter, but I am not quite sure how I would set it, if I don't know how many `/` are within the string. Even when I tried `url.split("/",1)` instead of  `url.split("/")` I get `undefined` for my `afterLastSlash` value.

Comment: You can always split on the slash, pop off the last value in the resulting array, then use join() to bring the rest of it back together if that's what you need.

Comment: Isn't `let url = https://learn.edu/d2l/login?sessionExpired=1&target=%2fd2l%2fhome` a syntax error?  `let url = 'https://learn.edu/d2l/login?sessionExpired=1&target=%2fd2l%2fhome'` is valid (with quotes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you array deconstruction is wrong it should be

```
let [x,y] = astring.split("/")
```

if you want `x` and `y` to contain the first two tokens from the array ...

Second, reading the docs of [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), the `limit` parameter limits the number of tokens in the result array. So if you do `var [a,b] = astring.split("/", 1)` obviously `b` will be undefined, because the result of `split` will only contain 1 element. The rest of the string is ignored ...

You can use [`url.lastIndexOf("/")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)  to get the index of the last `/` and then use [`url.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to get the string before and after that index

```js
let url = "https://learn.edu/d2l/login?sessionExpired=1&target=%2fd2l%2fhome"
let i = url.lastIndexOf("/");
if (i >= 0) {
  let beforeLastSlash = url.substring(0, i);
  let afterLastSlash = url.substring(i+1);
  console.log(beforeLastSlash);
  console.log(afterLastSlash);
}
```

Another possibility is to `split` by `/`, then removing the last element of the result with [`Array.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and then put back together the remaining array with [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
let 
  url = "https://learn.edu/d2l/login?sessionExpired=1&target=%2fd2l%2fhome",
  s = url.split("/"),
  afterLastSlash = s.pop(),
  beforeLastSlash = s.join("/");

console.log(beforeLastSlash);
console.log(afterLastSlash);
```